# Why RequestValidation not validate on AJAX request?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, security

I'm using MVC 4 and enable validation on requests:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
</system.web>
```

Why validation only works on FORM request not AJAX request? If a form request has a field which contains HTML text, ex: `'<html'>`  then validation will raise an error 'A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client ...'. But with a AJAX request which contains HTML text, why .NET validation doesn't raise an error?

And finally, I have a question: validation on AJAX request is useless?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ajax requests are indeed not influenced by RequestValidation by default. Although you can override this behavior and implement you own validation: [Security Issue in MVC AJAX](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2011/05/23/security-issue-in-asp-net-mvc3-jsonvalueproviderfactory.aspx)

This works for MVC3, but I don't know whether it'll work on MVC4 or 5. But you could definitely check it out.